# Why does my Eclipse toolbar not contain "Show Preview" or themes? How can I customize it to include them?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, eclipse-luna

I have added the Aptana 3 plugin, and in my Web perspective, not matter how I try to customize, I can't seem to add the "Show Preview" tool to my toolbar for my Web perspective.

How can I customize it to contain "Show Preview"? Without having to search for it every time through "quick access"?

I'm currently running:

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)

Any help is appreciated! Eclipse was recommended to me for web programming, rather than NetBeans, so I'm trying hard to figure out how to use it.

Comment: It may only be present when you open a file in the right editor.

Comment: but in youtube tutorials I've been mirroring from installation to example project, I am opening web perspective just like they are, but without this coveted "show preview" tool in my toolbar. I am beginning to suspect it is the something different to do with the luna version of eclipse?

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial? Again, is there an editor open when it's show? I ask because "Show Preview" would need *something* for which to show a preview.

Comment: here is the tutorial using eclipse indigo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GF2xxA1YFAo In my editor, I just used a default html template, editing it to display "hello world". Thanks for your patience and willingness to look into this!